# Magento : How to check if sidebar is empty

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to check if any of the sidebar on my 3-column layout has been rendered empty, and would like to add a custom block in sidebar, only when its empty.

Is there anyway to identify if a sidebar contains a block or not?

Answer (score 0):

well, for sure one way would be to query that specific block for children, like:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('right')->getSortedChildren();
```

'right' is in our case, right sidebar as far as i remember. Block name in layout xml.

UPDATE: actually there's also:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('right')->countChildren();
```

that returns integer of how many of them are there.

if you want to see if there's any content there (because blocks can have output or no), you could query for html in the block:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('right')->getChildHtml();
```

Comment: I understand these methods, but I am looking out for a solution, where I could provide layout configuration options in layout XML files, instead of writing up codes, in templates. Looking for a solution very similar to use of 'ifconfig' attribute used to place blocks in layouts

Comment: who said to do this in template? Do this inside your block _toHtml method and return something (or not) based on what countChildren returns.